# How to get a unique value from a column while returning the most recent non unique

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have a group of tables like this:

```
post_id | post_content | page_id     
   1         etc...        7
   2         text...       5
```

and

```
changelog_id | post_id | page_id |   changelog_date    | changelog_type
      1               2        5       02/02/2015 11:05         3
      2               2        5       02/02/2015 11:15         2
      3               1        7       03/01/2015 18:15         3
```

I want to return:

```
select distinct post_id, post_content, changelog_type, changelog_date
from posts p 
inner join logs l on l.post_id = p.post_id
where p.page_id = 5
```

BUT distinct wont wort because the changelog_date is not unique.
 i want my return to be like:

```
 post_id| post_content |  changelog_type   | changelog_date
   2        text...      02/02/2015 11:15         2
```

with the most recent entry of post_id with page_id and only ONE result per post_id.

I tried GROUP BY, but I get:

*Column 'page.pageId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

in my actual use I have 6 tables to get information from and I am using Inner join to get information from them all. I just need to reduce the returns by getting only one per instance of post_id.

Comment: Seems like the classic [groupwise maximum problem](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

Comment: You have tagged with MySQL, but that looks suspiciously like a SQL Server error message to me. Which product are you actually using?

Comment: You can have that error in MySQL depending on settings.

Comment: @Vatev I am aware of that, but the message in MySQL is something like *"Non-grouping field 'pageId' is used in SELECT clause"*, whereas the message posted in the question is word for word the same as the error message given by SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
select distinct post_id, post_content, changelog_type, MAX(changelog_date)
from posts p 
inner join logs l on l.post_id = p.post_id
where p.page_id = 5
group by post_id, post_content, changelog_type
```